# i want to pass variable in php to bootstrap modal to fetch corresponding data from database in same file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
<table class="table table-striped mytable">
<tbody>

<?php
$y="";
while($row=$rs3->fetch_assoc())
{   
    <?php
    $x=$row["P_Code"];
    $y=$row["P_Name"];?>
    <td> <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" class="mylink1 mylink" data-target="#modaltestForm"><?php echo $y;?></a></td>
<? 
}
?>
```

when i click on this link of P_Name then it will show a bootstrap modal in which i want fetch data from database based on product clicked

Comment: you forgot to ask a question, or to tell us what problems you have. Right now the answer is: "go ahead, do it!"

Comment: the modal is code is outside the loop .so it shows the last record id content.how could i pass id to modal

Comment: Open the modal in Javascript onClick function and pass your key value (from php) into that function.